# Safari won't exit out in iOS

Tags: javascript, safari

When I add my app to my iPhone homescreen, it works fine. But if I exit back to the home screen and re-open my app, the top status bar (with the clock, battery power, wifi signal, etc) shows and it won't let me exit out. The app still works perfectly but I'm stuck in Safari and can't get out.

I have to restart the phone and this keeps happening every time.

Comment: I have the same issue and it seems that it is a bug in iOS.

Comment: what does this has to do with javascript and Safari? Is there any code that we can see?

Comment: It's really convenient for Apple that there's a Safari bug that prevents web apps from behaving like apps downloaded from the App Store.